# XAMPP on Windows MYSQL Will start and then stop abruptly but APACHE works fine

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

Alright, I looked everywhere for a solution and none of them worked.  Yesterday, My XAMPP worked perfectly fine.  Today, I tried to start my MySQL service and it doesn't work.  Let me be more specific:  This is the XAMPP log:

```
Attempting to start MySQL app...
9:54:00 AM  [mysql]     Status change detected: running
9:54:01 AM  [mysql]     Status change detected: stopped
9:54:01 AM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
9:54:01 AM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
9:54:01 AM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another >method.
9:54:01 AM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
9:54:01 AM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
9:54:01 AM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
9:54:01 AM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forum
```

This is the error log:

```
016-03-23 09:54:00 1d04 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
160323  9:54:00 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
160323  9:54:00 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160323  9:54:00 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
160323  9:54:00 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
160323  9:54:00 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160323  9:54:00 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
160323  9:54:00 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
160323  9:54:00 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160323  9:54:00 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160323  9:54:00 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1665234 and 1665234 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 2110930 in the ib_logfiles!
160323  9:54:00 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
160323  9:54:00 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
160323  9:54:00 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
160323  9:54:00 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
160323  9:54:00 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
160323  9:54:01 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
160323  9:54:01 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
160323  9:54:01 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.22-72.0 started; log sequence number 2110930
160323  9:54:01 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
160323  9:54:01 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Apache works and is running btw.  The things that I tried:

Deleting the ibdata1 file. 
Changing the port in my.ini. 
Skype is not running.
Stopping World wide Web Publishing Service.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I figured it out myself.  So I looked into the windows event viewer and saw that some errors were coming from MySQL.  I clicked on the most recent one and found this.

> mysqld.exe: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed

I replaced all db files:  db.frm, db. MYD, and db.MYI (Copy these to desktop just in case) with the ones from backup.  And viola it works again.  All the data is there, even the ones I remember inserting in yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it is because I have MySQL Workbench installed, which also uses port 3306 for its own installation of MySQL.
So there are 2 installations of MySQL, and both trying to use port 3306. Workbench seemed to take precedence.

It was easiest to change XAMPP MySQL to use port 3308.

- From XAMPP Control Panel: Stop Apache and MySql.
- Edit `my.ini` (in some MySql installations this will be `my.cnf`; in others `my.ini`)
  It's location will depend on where you have installed XAMPP.  On my system I found it at `T:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini`.
  (The comparable file for my MySQL Workbench on my system is located at ``)
- Search for `3306` (or `port`); Replace with `3308`.
  There were 2 places where I replaced the line: `port            = 3306` with: `port            = 3308`
- Save
- From XAMPP Control Panel: Start Apache and MySql